# C++ (const char *) length is same but content is different In Swift

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, swift

I've function pointer in C++ which is holds

```
     function_pointer(const char*, unsigned long int){
    
           const char arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'};

             for (int i = 0; i<12; i++){
                  std::cout<<int(arr[i])<<" ";
              }

           SwiftCallingFunction(arr, 12);
    }
```

In swift side i can access as

```
    func function_pointer_swift (frameData: UnsafePointer<Int8>?, frameSize: UInt){

            let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: frameData.unsafelyUnwrapped, count: Int(frameSize));
            let a = Array(buffer)
                 for element in a {
                print(Int(element), terminator:" ")
             }

}
```

Up to here it is okay, as i know:

UnsafePointer -> Immutable (since char is const it is okay), and casting to Int8 because of char (signed 8 bit integer val).

Once i'm printing array on C++ and Swift some times i'm getting same value some times completely different.

For Example:

It prints (as expected):

```
CPP Prints   -> 1 2 3 4 5 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 
Swift Prints -> 1 2 3 4 5 97 98 99 100 101 102 103
```

But however some times

```
CPP Prints   -> 1 2 3 4 5 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 
Swift Prints -> -16 -57 -32 -127 2 0 0 0 40 -106 -127 13
```

CPP printing always same content but swift is not same it prints something like followings:

```
-16 -57 -32 -127 2 0 0 0 40 -106 -127 13 

1 2 3 4 5 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 

16 -64 -32 -127 2 0 0 0 40 -106 -127 13 

0 93 12 0 0 0 0 0 40 -106 -127 13 

-128 -44 -60 2 1 0 0 0 100 101 102 103
```

Comment: I see that CPP function doesn't print array passed in parameters. May be it's working wrong, not swift version?

Comment: I'm passing as arr actually, if u look function_pointer it is callback function.
SwiftCallingFunction(arr, 12);

And I can access sometime correct, sometimes wrong so I don't guess it is parameter misstake

Comment: You need turn on `Address Sanitizer`, `Detect use of stack after return`, `Undefined behaviour Sanitizer` in `Diagnostics`

Comment: I guess this is debug purpose but however after doing this, it's working fine. I'm really confused how this is solved the bug since it is debug tool. 
But it is works only for my static data which is "1 2 3 4 5 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 "

But if i use dynamic type instead of it, it is against some times correct sometimes wrong and there is no error on memory side. To be ensure it is working, i've just change size of it and it says heap overflow so debug tool is okay but if the error/misstake happens it says nothing to me. But it's good to know for next tries. Thank you

Comment: I've changed char * to char [] via strncpy, i'm getting same result now. Thank you :)